# How to define contract for both messaging and http API using sping-contract

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I have a situation where there are 2 services. Service A is exposing query API through HTTP endpoint and also is listening for incomming asynchronous command messages (service A owns both of CQRS contracts).

Service B is using both endpoints of service A: to GET data and to invoke commands.

While implementing contract (stub and tests) for HTTP flow is quite simple, configuring messaging part is a tricky for me and actually I've stucked at this one.

Docs says that there is publisher side test generation what is suitable for publishing event case where publisher owns the contract.

But how to makes it working for situation where message consumer owns the contract??

I can't figure out any solution on that one as I need to have a stub used in service A to verify if service A is properly consuming commands messages and also I need genereated tests on service B that will verify that service B if it is producing compliant command message.

I'd appreciate any help.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If service A is listening for messages then it's not owning the messaging contract. It's owned by the message producer

Comment: Well, I doubt that as if this command message would be invoked as async HTTP POST then which would be the owner of this contract?? From my point of view changing protocol shouldn't change ownership of the contract. It is defined by service A which is accepting it.

Comment: You're missing the point. Service A is the **producer** of the API and the **producer** of messages. It means that it owns the contract for HTTP and messaging. Service B is the **consumer** of both HTTP and messaging. It sends a request to Service A and receives messages from Service A via broker. No ownership was changed. You just misuse the terms. Or I misunderstood what you're writing ;)

Comment: Actually service A both receives http requests and consumes messages. Service B is sending both requests and aync messages to service A.

Comment: My bad... Service A is the **producer** of the API and the **consumer** of messages. It owns **only** contracts for HTTP. The messaging contracts are owned by Service B. Service B is the **producer** of messages. You should have an HTTP contract defined on the Service A side and a Stub Runner test to test if it can receive the message sent by Service B. Service B should have the messaging contract to assert whether the message is properly sent and Stub Runner test for HTTP.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't it lead us to dependency cycle as stubs are uploaded during service A|B CI build??

Comment: If you have a cycle between your apps then, yeah, what you have to do is ignore a stub runner test on one side until the jars got uploaded. Does this answer you question? If that's the case, I'll write an answer below so that you can accept it :)

Comment: Well, I'd rather not reconfiguring current CI/CD process but maybe we could have separate project for services contracts and CI/CD build that will upload stubs to maven repo?? Can we disable test generation during execution of contract-plugin? That's the only option for now I can give a try.

Comment: You can store contracts in a separate project - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_faq.html#_common_repo_with_contracts example https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/beer_contracts . You can not use `<extensions>true</extensions>` in Maven but manually provide which goals you want to execute (omit the test generation). In Gradle just disable `generateContractTests` task AFAIR

Answer (score 0):

Service A is the producer of the API and the consumer of messages. It owns only contracts for HTTP. The messaging contracts are owned by Service B. Service B is the producer of messages. You should have an HTTP contract defined on the Service A side and a Stub Runner test to test if it can receive the message sent by Service B. Service B should have the messaging contract to assert whether the message is properly sent and Stub Runner test for HTTP

That might lead to a dependency cycle. If you have a cycle between your apps then, yeah, what you have to do is ignore a stub runner test on one side until the jars got uploaded.

You've asked about storing contracts in a separate repository. You can do it - here are the docs https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_faq.html#_common_repo_with_contracts and here is an example https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/beer_contracts

You've asked about not generating the tests for some reason (IMO that's a wrong thing to do). You can not use `<extensions>true</extensions>` in Maven but manually provide which goals you want to execute (omit the test generation). In Gradle just disable `generateContractTests` task AFAIR